# Html Language how change text to LINK

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I have a `html code`. Can you help me to  code so that i can make a normal text to a `link`.Basically i want to change text that showing in `LINK-COLUMN` it will react like a `link` now it is only text.

I am trying but nothing found helpful. I am new in Html programming.

[image: HTML PAGE PREVIEW LINK]

```js
$(function() {


  var people = [];

  $.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/c307c', function(data) {
    $.each(data.video, function(i, f) {

      var tblRows = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.Id + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + f.video + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.date + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.time + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.video + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.image + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + f.videoDuration + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.liveStatus + "</td>" + "<td>" + "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + f.video + "</td>" + "<td><div><img src=" + f.image + "></div></td>" + "</tr>"
      $(tblRows).appendTo("#userdata tbody");

    });

  });

});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="profile">
    <table id="userdata" width="50%" border="2">
      <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>VIDEO NAME</th>
        <th>DATE</th>
        <th>TIME</th>
        <th>VIDEO LINK</th>
        <th>VIDEO IMAGE</th>
        <th>DURACTION</th>
        <th>LIVE STATUS</th>
        <th>LINK </th>
        <th>PLAY</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet and added S to HTTP:// api. I also removed a stray </div>

Answer (score 1):

```
  <script>

   $(function() {


  var people = [];

  $.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/c307c',function(data) {
      $.each(data.video, function(i, f) {

        var link = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+ f.video;
         var tblRows = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.Id + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + f.video + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.date + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.time + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.video + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.image + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + f.videoDuration + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.liveStatus + "</td>" + "<td><a target='_blank' href='"+link+"'>"+link+"</a></td>"  + "<td><div><img src=" + f.image + "></div></td>" + "</tr>";
          $(tblRows).appendTo("#userdata tbody");

    });

  });

});
</script>
```

I have just added an anchor tag in the HTML that is dynamically creating. and I have created a link variable and passed that as a link in that anchor tag to avoid link adding repetition.

**If you want to open a link in a new tab, add_blank to anchor tag or else remove it if the link is to be opened in the same window.**

Comment: This is the correct solution, but please include a description of what you've changes and why it helps so that the OP and future visitors can learn something useful from your answer.

Comment: Thanks sir but it should open in same window then

Comment: you want to open a link in the same window or another?

Comment: If you want to open a link in a new tab, add_blank to anchor tag or else remove it if the link is to be opened in the same window. Check my updated answer

Comment: @RAMAN have you got what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Use html hyperlink tag

```
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/..."></a>
```

Comment: please edit my code and paste sir i tried but not working

Answer (score 0):

> you can use `<a>` element (or anchor element), with its href
>   attribute

for more ref check [DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

```
  <ul>
      <li><a href="https://example.com">Website</a></li>
      <li><a href="mailto:m.bluth@example.com">Email</a></li>
      <li><a href="tel:+123456789">Phone</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

Using an anchor tag

```
"<td><a href=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + f.video + "\">" + f.video + "</a></td>
```

like this

```js
$(function() {
  $.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/c307c', function(data) {
    var tblRows = [];
    $.each(data.video, function(i, f) {
      tblRows.push("<tr><td>" + f.Id + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + f.video + "</td><td>" + f.date + "</td><td>" + f.time + "</td><td>" + f.video + "</td><td>" + f.image + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + f.videoDuration + "</td><td>" + f.liveStatus + "</td>" +
        "<td><a href=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + f.video + "\">" + f.video + "</a></td><td><img src=" + f.image + "></td></tr>")

    });
    $(tblRows.join("")).appendTo("#userdata tbody");

  });

});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="profile">
    <table id="userdata" width="50%" border="2">
      <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>VIDEO NAME</th>
        <th>DATE</th>
        <th>TIME</th>
        <th>VIDEO LINK</th>
        <th>VIDEO IMAGE</th>
        <th>DURACTION</th>
        <th>LIVE STATUS</th>
        <th>LINK </th>
        <th>PLAY</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```